# Coloring of nodes in a sensor networks

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, graphs

I have weighted graph for sensor networks with aggregation nodes and sensors. There is a edge between two nodes associated with a weight.
Higher the weight, stronger the interference between the aggregation nodes if they have same color.

I need to perform graph coloring of these nodes with just K colors. The nodes with higher edge weight should/must have different colors.

What is an efficient way to do the optimal coloring?

Ideas:

May be the coloring of such a big network is too difficult. Instead we can have clusters of nodes and then do the intra-cluster coloring. But then we need to take care of inter-cluster interference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend first trying to solve the problem directly. For each edge $(i,j)$, let $c_{ij}$ be the edge weight. Let binary decision variable $x_{ik}$ indicate whether node $i$ is assigned color $k$. The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} \sum_k x_{ik} x_{jk}$$ subject to $\sum_k x_{ik} = 1$ for all $i$. You can call an MIQP solver or linearize the quadratic objective. To linearize, for each edge $(i,j)$ with $c_{ij}>0$, introduce binary (or just nonnegative) decision variable $y_{ij}$ to represent $\sum_k x_{ik} x_{jk}$, impose additional constraints
$y_{ij} \ge x_{ik} + x_{jk} - 1$, and minimize $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} y_{ij}$.

Comment: you can see that there are large number of nodes. As it is clear from the problem description that one node will more more likely 5 to 6 nodes, i.e., most of $c_{i,j}$ are zero. How to take this into consideration o make the problem smaller/simpler?

Comment: I would not be surprised if this problem can be solved quickly for a sparse graph with 500 nodes.  You do not need $y_{ij}$ or its constraint if $c_{ij}=0$.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is the same model I suggested here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/10238/500

Comment: the second constraint can be expressed as:                         for $c=1:C$,
      for $i=1:N-1$,
            for $j=i+1:N$,
                 if $w_{ij}>0$
$y_{ij}\ge x_{ic}+x_{jc}-1$, 
end if,
end for,
end for,
end for. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that looks right, assuming that you have changed $K$ to $C$ and that $w_{ij}$ is defined for all pairs with $i<j$ instead of just for all edges in the network.

Comment: It is because $w_{ij}=w_{ji}$. Isn't enough to form the constraints like this?

Comment: Yes, you should restrict to $i<j$, but I meant that you can restrict even further to just the edges $(i,j)$ if the graph is not complete.

Comment: what happens if it is not possible to have different colors at two nodes of an edge with the given C? My objective is to do the coloring with C colors in the best possible way. If the edge has very low weight, we ca allow the nodes of the edge to have same color.

Comment: Yes, this model allows such improper colorings. For edge $(i,j)$, if nodes $i$ and $j$ are assigned the same color $k$, then $x_{ik}=x_{jk}=1$, the constraints enforce $y_{ij}=1$, and the weight $c_{ij}$ is accrued.