# Distributed coloring of nodes of sensor ntwork

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, graphs

I have the same graph coloring problem as in

[Coloring of nodes of a sensor network](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10321/coloring-of-nodes-of-a-sensor-network)

@RobPratt and @prubin have proposed some very good solutions.

This time I am or interested in distributed coloring schemes considering the large size of the graph. I have around 3000-4000 nodes.

The problem remains the same....[copied from @RobPratt's answer]

For each edge $(i,j)$, let $c_{ij}$ be the edge weight. Let binary decision variable $x_{ik}$ indicate whether node $i$ is assigned color $k$. The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} \sum_k x_{ik} x_{jk}$$ subject to $\sum_k x_{ik} = 1$ for all $i$.

To linearize, for each edge $(i,j)$ with $c_{ij}>0$, introduce binary (or just nonnegative) decision variable $y_{ij}$ to represent $\sum_k x_{ik} x_{jk}$, impose additional constraints
$y_{ij} \ge x_{ik} + x_{jk} - 1$, and minimize $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} y_{ij}$.

I am looking for a fully distributed solution. at any epoch, one node can talk or share info with only its neighbors.

The node can take color randomly in the very beginning. Ho do we proceed from there?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Kuifje I am looking for a distributed solution for this problem.

Comment: 3000-4000 nodes is not that big. You can get good solution in a few seconds without any distributed algorithm

Comment: @fontanf would you please refer me to some solution for my problem which can be solved in just few seconds.

Comment: @fontanf some of the DIMACS coloring problems with approx 100 nodes cannot be solved optimally

Comment: @Kuifje if the problem is NP-complete, exact algorithms are exponential in the instance size. Distributing them won't make it possible to solve much larger instances

Comment: @KGM a good implementation of the local search algorithm suggested here https://or.stackexchange.com/a/10328/4551 should already provide decent solutions quickly

Comment: @fontanf I agree. I was just pointing out that coloring 3000 nodes may be untracktable in his case.